# How the crap do I display code on this site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

When I try to put in my code snippets it never works.
If I press space 4 times, it only monotypes the first line after I paste in my code. No freaking way are we supposed to go in and put 4 spaces on ever line??

Comment: Paste your code, select it all and press the { } button.

Comment: -1 for the title, didn't even bother to read the post.

Comment: Do you see the "help" menu?

Answer (score 6):

Select the code that you want formatted, then click the { } button from the toolbar. This will automatically format your code without having to press space

Comment: You can also select all the code and pres `ctrl-K`

Comment: "K" as in Kind of Kooky Key you Kneed to Know.

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to go in and put 4 spaces on ever line. There's a button for it in the toolbar of the editor.